# how do you connect to your email using java (not javamail)

Tags: java, javascript, email, netbeans

Is there a way to connect to your email inbox in java (using netbeans IDE) without the use of JavaMail API? I have been searching for a way to do it without the use of that API as I am trying to construct a program which reads my email and stores them into a database using sql server. is there a way?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the JavaMail API? Ofcourse you can implement the relevant protocols yourself, but why would you want to do that when there's already a well-known library for it?

Comment: The fact is that I would use it but this program will be used on more then one computer which do not have the api, thus not making it compatible to use.

Comment: As I said the last time this question was asked, if you really don't want to use the APIs that available to you, you are going to have to implement the protocols your self, like [pop3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt) and [imap](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501). This an significant amount of work when you consider the availability of the a JavaMail libraries. Instead of wasting time trying to rework what is already available, why not try and solve the issue of installing appropriate libraries on your target machines...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Socket** classes.
Send message directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JavaMail? There are other libraries available, such as [ChilKat's](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-imap.asp) - or you could talk POP3/IMAP directly, you know open a socket on port 110/143 and issue commands and read the responses (which is what the libraries will do for you).

If you have to provide a single JAR file, you can merge the JavaMail classes (and dependencies) with your own code, or - depending on your target infrastructure - a WAR or EAR might be more appropriate.

Cheers,

Comment: The fact is that I would use it but this program will be used on more then one computer which do not have the api, thus not making it compatible to use.

Comment: @user3170479 Why can't you package JavaMail (or any other API for that matter) with your program?

Comment: which means you don't really know much about Java at all, since that is very, very basic stuff. I would at least work through an entire book for beginners before you start to do anything seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the hard way, you can write e.g. a POP3 client in Java yourself.
Use Socket, connect to the right host and port (port is usually 110) and start issuing POP3 commands.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: The fact is that I would use it but this program will be used on more then one computer which do not have the api, thus not making it compatible to use.

Comment: @user3170479 I see. Well, OK, you can use this approach I suggested. I see others are now suggesting it too.